# wget can't connect to domain on same server

Tags: debian, wget

I'm trying to run the following command on the server. The site example.com is hosted on the same server.

```
wget --spider "https://example.com/script.php?actions=1"
```

Response:

```
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2018-05-03 16:50:48-- https://example.com/script.php?actions=1
Resolving example.com (example.com)... [CORRECT_IP_ADDRESS]
Connecting to example.com (example.com)|[CORRECT_IP_ADDRES]|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.
```

but it fails with a timeout. It's the same with "http".

wget resolves the domain to the correct IP-address (CORRECT_IP_ADDRESS) and pingning example.com gives the same IP.

The site is up and running and can be accessed from anywhere using any browser. I can successfully run the same command from any other server (inside or outside our own network) without problems.

The server is running a standard Debian 9 setup with Apache, PHP 7 and MySql. The server has two ethernet ports but only uses one. Static external IP.

After some comments (thank you all!) I have updated my post with the result from the suggested tests.

I have tried the following commands from the within the same server:

```
telnet example.com => Connection refused  
telnet example.com 443 => Connection timed out  
telnet IP_ADDRESS => Connection refused  
telnet IP_ADDRESS 443 => Connection timed out  
telnet localhost => Connection refused
telnet localhost 443 => SUCCESS
```

Running the same commands from any other server gives:

```
telnet example.com => Resource temporarily unavailable  
telnet example.com 443 => SUCCESS  
telnet IP_ADDRESS => Resource temporarily unavailable  
telnet IP_ADDRESS 443 => SUCCESS
```

Any idea where/how to start troubleshooting?

Comment: try curl and ip address and pass hostname

Comment: Are you running a firewall on your example.com server?  Can you telnet to example.com 443 from the server using both the IP address and FQDN?

Comment: @mdeora curl also fails with a timeout, if run from the same server. From any other server curl works.

Comment: @L.Ray I have not installed/enabled any firewall on the server but when I try to telnet example.com from the same server it fails with "Connection refused". Telnet from any other server to example.com works better - "Trying IP_ADDRESS" for about 30 seconds and then it fails with "Unable to connect to remote host: Resource temporarily unavailable".

Comment: Hmm, I think `telnet example.com 443` was meant. The reason I suspect you mis-interpreted is that this command should be able to connect OK in the same situations that `wget https://example.com` works. But you said the wget command worked and telnet didn't, if you ran them on a different computer.

Comment: Thanks @sourcejedi. I have updated my post with the results.

Comment: I'm not sure what L.Ray was hoping to find though, "Connection timed out" seems fairly clear already. Anyway, not getting an immediate reaction *when you try to connect to the default telnet port* from a different server, would normally be a sign that *something* is dropping packets in that test. I don't know exactly why the eventual error would about resources though.  The Linux TCP stack itself will always respond (to either refuse or accept the connection), it is firewalls that filter this to provide "stealth".

Comment: Probably the temporary resources error means an EAGAIN return, which can occur when the timeout is a shorter one set by the userspace program: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14370767/799204

Comment: If you want to prove that there is no iptables firewall on the server itself, run `iptables save`. This assumes the IP address you mention is IPv4 only, not an IPv6 address. If you want to start narrowing down an intermediate hop at the IP layer which drops packets, I suggest a "TCP traceroute".  You either want the `tcptraceroute` command or a traceroute command which supports `traceroute -T`. Again, the proof I'm working from here is the command using the default telnet port. The corresponding port number you would need to specify for the tcp traceroute is port 23.